# text in textfield

Tags: java

After selecting file using browse button into textfield and selecting checkbox that checkbox radio buttons and run should be enabled.How can i do this in swing using java code?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit.  It is unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with selecting a file in Swing:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int choice = chooser.showSaveDialog(MainFrame.this);
if (choice != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    return;
File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

That block of code will open a File dialog and wait for a user to select a file.  Then the selected file will be stored into `selectedFile`.

You need to better clarify what you are asking for if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

[`JFileChooser`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), suggested by [Justin Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598/justin-nelson-jjnguy), has an [`addActionListener()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) method. By implementing the [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface, your [`actionPerformed()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) method  will be called to signal various user actions. You can enable buttons and set fields there. The tutorial [*How to Use File Choosers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) shows several examples.